# I have to make this file thru 'knit to HTML' but it doesn't work at all

Tags: r

I am trying to knit to HTML what I am doing now
but it doesn't work by sending errors

I am using MacBook and there is an error in R Markdown space at the bottom 
it says

```
Line 67 Error in colMeans(datawithoutsex): 'x' must be numeric calls: 
<anonymous> ... withCallingHandler -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> 
colMeans Execution halted
```

**EXERCISE 4 -? Exploratory Data Analysis**

````
```{r}
datawithoutsex <- data2019[,-1]

colMeans(datawithoutsex)

x <- data2019$stadiometer1

y <- data2019$stadiometer2

plot (x, y, main = "Scatterplot between stadiometer1 and stadiometer2", xlab ="stadiometer1", ylab = "stadiometer2", pch= 20, frame= FALSE)
```
````

as you can see, I can't see any error and it worked previously
I still don't get why it makes an error when I call Knit to HTML

I just need a HTML file

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear knitr cache and then knit to HTML again

Comment: it's below 'knit to HTML' option

Comment: it still makes the same error, I cleared the cache tho

Comment: we should see how datawithoutsex looks like in order to help you, then

Comment: I deleted some lines with errors and then it rendered knit to HTML
but I can't submit it without them